# Supplementary material

Tags: supplements

In reference to the patent: [WO2016149578A1](https://www.lens.org/images/patent/WO/2016149578/A1/WO_2016_149578_A1.pdf)

This patent mentions a file filled with supplementary material (mentioned in section [0002]). Where can I find this file?

Thanks in advance.

Sincerely,
Brandon

Comment: @robertcartaino To be fair, this person is not asking a production or technology question. He is asking a question about how to interpret the claims. His problem is he is not seeing the figures that describe the sequences. If he went to a better patent source he could see this such as https://www.lens.org/images/patent/WO/2016149578/A1/WO_2016_149578_A1.pdf. I believe this should be reopened.

Comment: @Donquikong  Could you please consider reopening this question? I do not find it off topic in its present form. Look at my other comment.

Comment: That's right, Eric Shain. I just want to be able to read the sequences. If I have a sequence of my own, how will I know if I'm infringing on someone else's patent if I can't read their sequence?

Comment: Google patents, while fast, is somewhat unreliable in providing the patents's figures. If you use the link I provided, you will find the whole patent including the figures which specify the sequences.

Comment: Thanks, Eric. I think I found where I can find my answer. I'll modify my question.

Comment: Also understand that the document you linked is not yet a patent and the claims will probably change before and if it is granted.

Comment: Just to make it completely clear, the specification for the sequences are in the application's figures that are in the patent application. All you have to do is click on this link: https://www.lens.org/images/patent/WO/2016149578/A1/WO_2016_149578_A1.pdf.

Comment: Huh. Good to know. As you can probably tell, my knowledge of patent law is rudimentary at best. However, I thought it was weird how on of the claims in this patent appeared to be in conflict with a claim in another patent from 1999.

Comment: Again, this is not yet a patent and the claims will probably change before it gets granted (if ever). If you have a specific question about one claim vs. another, that may be a good question in itself. I'd suggest a separate question however.

Comment: Fig. 5 has the most useful information, but throughout the patent, it refers to seq no 1: to seq no: 40 or so. Fig 5. shows a partial AA sequence, followed by known proteins that I assume are conjoined to this sequence. That's enough Information to deduce the sequence of seq. 29 and 30, as well as the 2 CARs. Table 1 also has data for seq 29, 30, 39, and 40. However, the other sequences referenced in the patent I can't find.

Comment: I think the information I'm lookiing for is provided as a txt file mentioned in [0002]. So I've changed my question. Thanks for all the help Eric :) I'll keep in mind that it's not a patent yet.

Comment: Have you tried searching for the application on Espacenet? https://worldwide.espacenet.com/?locale=en_EP

Comment: Just tried it. It is a lot of information to comb through. I still haven't found what I'm looking for, but but I'll keep combing. Thanks.

Comment: @EricShain I didn't see that you pinged me (I don't know why). Anyways, patent applications have dossiers with all the files. Normally espacenet has a link to them, in this case it's not working though. Try: https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/detail.jsf?docId=WO2016149578&recNum=1&tab=PCTDocuments&maxRec=&office=&prevFilter=&sortOption=&queryString=

Comment: Pinging could be case-sensitive, I'll try, you tell me: @ericshain . I flagged the question for moderator intervention because I think it should be reopened too.

Comment: @DonQuiKong I got your ping

Comment: @EricShain then I don't know.

Comment: Thank you both very much. The patentscope.wipo.int link had the file I was looking for.

Comment: @user19686  Since you were able to find what you needed, you should right it up as an answer. It might help someone else in the future.